# wine и запись текста в файл

Tags: linux, ubuntu, файлы, desktop, wine

ubuntu 14, wine

Есть программа, которая автоматически создает файл и наполняет его логами в ходе своего выполнения. В windows все работает нормально, а в ubuntu через wine файл создается, но не наполняется текстом. В чем может быть проблема?

Возможно нужно что-то подключить?

Проблема: софт не записывает логи в файл. Но сам файл создает

Comment: Запускайте wine в эмуляторе терминала, он там много сообщений пишет в stderr.

Comment: запускаю так всегда. Там ничего интересного, в этот раз. Лишь:
[code]fixme:winsock:convert_aiflag_w2u_Unhandled_windows_AI_xxx flags 8[/code]

гуглил, но ничего не нашел. Понятия не имею, что оно хочет. Да, и я сомневаюсь, что эта строка связана с наполнением файла. Скорее, другая часть софта что-то хочет...

Comment: А что за прога? Какая-то известная?

Answer (score 1):

Помогла установка wine staging